# R applying a data frame on another data frame

Tags: r, plyr, apply

I have two data frames.

```
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame( 
  id       = factor(rep(1:24, each = 10)),
  price    = runif(20)*100,
  quantity = sample(1:100,240, replace = T)
  )

df2 <- data.frame(
  id          = factor(seq(1:24)),
  eq.quantity = sample(1:100, 24, replace = T) 
)
```

I would like to use `df2$­eq.quantity` to find the closest absolute value compared to `df$quantity`, by the factor variable, `id`. I would like to do that for each `id` in `df2` and bind it into a new data-frame, called `results`.

I can do it like this for each individually ID:

```
d.1  <- df2[df2$id == 1, 2]
df.1 <- subset(df, id == 1)
id.1 <- df.1[which.min(abs(df.1$quantity-d.1)),]
```

Which would give the solution:

```
id     price      quantity
1      66.60838       84
```

But I would really like to be able to use a smarter solution, and also gathered the results into a dataframe, so if I do it manually it would look kinda like this:

```
results <- cbind(id.1, id.2, etc..., id.24)
```

I had some trouble giving this question a good name?

Comment: Are you sure your "solution" is right?

Comment: Your right, I did one of my data-sets before i set the seed.... Changed it now in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge the two datasets and use `lapply` to perform the function on each id.

```
df3 <- merge(df,df2,all.x=TRUE,by="id")

diffvar <- function(df){ 
df4 <- subset(df3, id == df) 
df4[which.min(abs(df4$quantity-df4$eq.quantity)),]
}

resultslist <- lapply(levels(df3$id),function(df) diffvar(df))
```

Combine the resulting list elements in a dataframe:

```
resultsdf <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(resultslist), ncol=4, byrow=T))
```

Or more easy:

```
library(plyr)
resultsdf <- ddply(df3, .(id), function(x)x[which.min(abs(x$quantity-x$eq.quantity)),])
```

Comment: Thanks, I hope you can quickly enlighten me: I don't get exactly what `subset(df3, id == df)` does? Or I understand it, but you cant use it in the console? Also, what does it do that you write `function(df) diffvar(df))` instead of just `diffvar(df)`?

Answer (score 2):

data.tables are smart!

Adding this to your current example...

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(df)
dt2 = data.table(df2)
setkey(dt, id)
setkey(dt2, id)
dt[dt2, dif:=abs(quantity - eq.quantity)]
dt[,list(price=price[which.min(dif)], quantity=quantity[which.min(dif)]), by=id]
```

result:

```
 dt[,list(price=price[which.min(dif)], quantity=quantity[which.min(dif)]), by=id]
    id      price quantity
 1:  1 66.6083758       84
 2:  2 29.2315840       19
 3:  3 62.3379442       63
 4:  4 54.4974836       31
 5:  5 66.6083758        6
 6:  6 69.3591292       13
...
```